# Looking for help on deciding a name for a character

Tags: characters

I can't decide what to name a certain character. It could either be Hamu or Humu. 
The other names of the characters would be Japanese, and the story is a fantasy setting with Japanese aspects thrown in.

His name is supposed to be, and mean “Hum”. I'm worried that my English audience would find this confusing.

However Humu or Fumu (H and F are similiar) are Japanese onomatopoeia for the “hmmm” sound.

I kind of like Humu, precisely for this reason, because he's supposed to be named after his father who carries the name “Taisho” meaning "to hum or sing softly".

Please, I'm not looking for advise on Japanese, just honest opinions about the character's name.

Comment: Welcome to Writers.  Questions like "what should I name my character" aren't a good fit for Stack Exchange, as they boil down to "I dunno, which do *you* like better?", i.e. opinion-based discussions.  A question about whether the spelling difference you're talking about would confuse readers could be on-topic, if you tell us something about your readers (like where in the world they live).  Please check out our short [tour].  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite clear what you're asking. Is your question whether "Hamu" or "Humu" is the better name for a character for an English-speaking audience?

If that's it, I can assure you that it makes zero difference to someone whose only language is English. Neither name carries any meaning or significance. They're both just sounds.

Comment: And I'd like to add that you'll have to explain all the meanings of the namnes in the text, if you want your non-Japanese readers to be aware of them.

Comment: @what Absolutely. If those meanings are important to the story, you'd have to explain them. If not, the names are just sounds.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very subjective Q. I don't know Japanese but to me **Fumu** "sounds" the most Japanese and reminds me of the Fugu fish.

To me **Hamu** sounds like "ham", or "Hamburger" as in a Hamuger, Hammurabi, or Hammer. 
Also, it is a name used in [several countries](http://www.namespedia.com/details/Hamu), has meaning in [Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamu_Shiru), and [Hungarian](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-meaning-of/hungarian-word-5d9ee027e4015e424b82ec4d2453bd1903827154.html), not forgetting the text “hmu”, or [hit me up.](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110630162120AA0yIBY). **Famu** would be even worse.

To me **Humu** sounds like hum, him, hummer, humbug, humus, human, humongous, humor. 
You find Humu in [Swedish and Swahili](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/humu). It is also a name found in [4 countries](http://www.namespedia.com/details/Humu).  A humu humu is also a [Hawaiian triggerfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reef_triggerfish) and a [Skating longboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cR0t5_SAdV0). Plus it is a [Maori hip bone](http://maoridictionary.co.nz/word/1568) and is apparently English slang for [beautiful](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=humu)

Though to be fair **Fumu** is also an acronym for [fuck up move up](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fumu) or [“foul up…”](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/FUMU) 
It is also Chinese for [elders](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=fumu) , has meaning in [Corsican](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fumu), and [Esperanto](http://www.wordsense.eu/fumu/), and is a [Swahili name](http://www.namesite.com/content/fumu)

In spite of that I like **Fumu** the best for a Japanese character, though **Umu** without the H, which is an [alternative spelling](http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/search/?keyword=umu&submitSearch=Search+SFX&x=)
 of Humu could also do.